# Computation of the Force acting on an electric dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dipole

I’m having trouble computing the force on an electric dipole. I will simplify the problem so that I can only post the problematic part. There is a point charge $q$ at the origin of our Cartesian coordinate system. It’s electric field expressed in spherical coordinates is:
$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$$
Now imagine we have a small cylindrical charge distribution of radius $a$, height $L$ and volume charge density:
$$\rho(z)=\rho_0 \frac{z}{L}, \rho_0=const$$
placed along the $y$ axis and symmetrically to the plane $z=0$, very far from the origin, whose dipole moment, which I computed is:
$$\mathbf{p}=(0,0,p_z), p_z=\frac{1}{12}\rho_0\pi a^2L^2\mathbf{\hat{k}}$$
Basically, a physical dipole oriented along the $z$ axis and placed along the y-axis at a distance $d$, at a point which I will call $P=(0,d,0)$. Now, I tried computing the force on it by applying the formula(I chose a different notation $x_1=x,x_2=y,\cdots$, but it’s pretty much obvious):
$$\mathbf{F}=(\mathbf{p} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{E}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\mathbf{\hat{x}_i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{3}p_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}E_i \right)$$
In our case, only the third component of the $\bf(p \cdot \nabla)$ operator does not vanish. So we just have to apply $p_z\partial_z$ to each of three Cartesian components of the external electric field.
Now if I work in general, our electric field has all three Cartesian components, in particular I tried to express it like this:
$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}(\sin\theta\cos\phi \mathbf{\hat{i}}+\sin\theta\sin\phi \mathbf{\hat{j}} +\cos\theta \mathbf{\hat{k}})$$
Now I have a doubt: is the formula for the force acting on a dipole to be interpreted as:
$$ \mathbf{F}=(\mathbf{p} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{E}|_{P} $$
Namely, can I already substitute the correct values for the angular variables ($\theta=\pi/2=\phi$)? If this is the case, then I guess I did right and obtained:
$$F_i=p_z\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial z}, i =[1,2,3]$$
But in our case we have that:
$$\mathbf{E}=(0,E_y,0), E_y=\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{\hat{j}}}{d^2}$$
In the end, if everything I did is correct, I would have:
$$\mathbf{F}=(0,F_y,0)$$
Where:
$$F_y=p_z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{1}{d^2} \right)=0$$
Well, I checked the solution given by my professor and it turns out that:
$$\mathbf{F}=\nabla \left( \frac{p_z z q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r ^3}  \right)|_{\vec{r}=d\hat{j}}$$
Hence:
$$\mathbf{F}=(0,0,\frac{p_z q}{4\pi \epsilon _0 d^3})$$
Can someone explain to me how to obtain those results? Are my computations completely wrong? How can they obtain a $z$ component to the force? I suppose I made some mistakes when expressing the field from spherical to Cartesian coordinates, but I honestly don’t know where precisely. The only things I can guarantee as of now is that the dipole moment I computed is correct and so is the electric field.

Comment: But the volume charge density exhibits a direct dependence from $z$. How can it be constant if I may ask?

Comment: The charge density is $\rho = \rho_0z $ so the integrand for the electric dipole is is $\rho_0 z^2$ (whose integral does not vanish)

Comment: @hyportnex I believe you misread the expression. I’ll write more clearly for everybody

Comment: @SolubleFish you are are right, I misread, or rather carelessly read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the formula $\mathbf{E}=(0,E_y,0), E_y=\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{\hat{j}}}{d^2}$ only holds on the $y$ axis, which is not enough to determine the derivatives in the formula $\mathbf F = p_z \partial_z \mathbf E$.

Put another way, we have :
$$\mathbf E = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat r}$$
This expression depends on $z$ **in two places** : $r = \sqrt{x^2  +y^2 + z^2}$ and :
$$\mathbf{\hat r} \equiv\frac{1}{r}\mathbf r = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2  +y^2 + z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2  +y^2 + z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2  +y^2 + z^2}}\right)$$
As you correctly calculated, we have $$\partial_z d|_P = 0$$
However, the other derivative is non zero :
$$\partial_z \mathbf{\hat r}|_P = (0,0,\frac{1}{d})$$
Therefore :
\begin{align}
\mathbf F &= (\mathbf p \cdot\mathbf \nabla)\mathbf E|_P \\
&= p_z \partial_z \left(\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat r} \right)\Big|_P \\
&=\frac{qp_z}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{d^2}\partial_z \mathbf{\hat r}|_P \\
&= \left(0,0,\frac{qp_z}{4\pi\epsilon_0d^3} \right)
\end{align}

Another way to see this, which is apparently what your professor did, is do write the electric force as the gradient of the potential energy, which, in the dipole approximation is :
$$V = \int \text d^3 \mathbf x V(\mathbf x)\rho(\mathbf x) \simeq \mathbf p \cdot\mathbf E|_P = \frac{qp_z z}{4\pi\epsilon_0 d^3} $$

Comment: I’m not quite sure the expression for $\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ is correct, I mean it cannot have an $x/z$ component. I think you meant the general position vector $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$. Also $d$ is the distance on the $y$ axis so it can’t be expressed the way you did so I assume you were referring to $r$ again. So if I understand correctly, I can’t already consider $\vec{E}|_P$ in the formula for the force but I gotta compute for a general point $\mathbf{r}$ and then substitute the values of our point of interest

Comment: Oh you edited my bad, I was writing the final comment and didn’t see it yet

Comment: Exactly, you are computing derivatives of the field $\vec E(\vec r)$, so knowing its value only at a point is not enough. You compute the field at a general point, take the derivative and then evaluate at the point of interest.